# yarn web ui for the running flink application can't be opened

Tags: apache-flink

I am using flink 1.3 and I have submitted a flink application with the job mode as:

```
flink run -m yarn-cluster  ....
```

From the console, I have seen that the applition has been startup, and I am able to see the sink to mysql.

But, when I navigate to this running application on the yarn web ui, and click it to open the flink web ui,

The flink ui is not opened, and  an error occurs as follows, I would ask what is wrong here, thanks!

```
16:05:01.858 [nioEventLoopGroup-3-2] ERROR org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.files.StaticFileServerHandler - Caught exception
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: null
    at io.netty.util.ReferenceCountUtil.touch(ReferenceCountUtil.java:77)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.touch(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:116)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:345)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.router.Handler.routed(Handler.java:62)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.router.DualAbstractHandler.channelRead0(DualAbstractHandler.java:57)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.http.router.DualAbstractHandler.channelRead0(DualAbstractHandler.java:20)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.HttpRequestHandler.channelRead0(HttpRequestHandler.java:108)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.webmonitor.HttpRequestHandler.channelRead0(HttpRequestHandler.java:66)
    at io.netty.channel.SimpleChannelInboundHandler.channelRead(SimpleChannelInboundHandler.java:105)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:438)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:310)
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:284)
    at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:253)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1434)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:965)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:646)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:581)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:498)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:460)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:884)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: What exact version of flink do you run 1.3.0? This looks like a classpath problem.  Due you run your cluster on yarn you might have another netty version on your classpath. Maybe you can check and post the classpath which is used to start the yarn-application.

Comment: Yes，it is 1.3.0, let me try, thanks!

Comment: Thanks @TobiSH, I did have netty packaged in my application jar, it works after I exclude it, thanks a lot to help me out!  Could you please make your comment as an answer?

Comment: of course :-) thanks for the vote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exact version of flink do you run 1.3.0? This looks like a classpath problem. Due you run your cluster on yarn you might have another netty version on your classpath. Maybe you can check and post the classpath which is used to start the yarn-application.